# How to get dpkg working again?

Tags: 10.04, dpkg

i tried to install sqlite3 on ubuntu 10.04 by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

this gave me the message

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

so i tried the "sudo dpkg --configure -a", no error. I tried to install sqlite3 again. This time it showed what updates will be done. So i continued and received this error message (partially translated from greman):

```
Unpacking substitution for ubuntu-docs ...
dpkg: ../../src/archives.c:763: tarobject: Assertion »r == stab.st_size« not fullfilled 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

i hope that some experts in here can help me :)

Comment: is it possible to delete the /bin/dpkg and download it with wget again, to configure/make/make install it ?

Comment: If you try something like `apt-get install ruby` will that fail with the same error?

Comment: delete /bin/dpkg? are you crazy? The right way to break the system.

Comment: @Aleksandr
any kind of installation fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start troubleshooting by checking the integrity to your dpkg.

Here are all the dpkg files for Ubuntu 11.04 with docs and directories filtered out:

http://biocluster.ucr.edu/~alevchuk/dpkg-1.16.0~ubuntu7-file-list

You you post the checksums of you're files. To get those run:

```
wget http://biocluster.ucr.edu/~alevchuk/dpkg-1.16.0~ubuntu7-file-list
cat dpkg-1.16.0~ubuntu7-file-list | xargs md5sum > my-dpkg-checksums
```

Then please post the **my-dpkg-checksums** file so we can compare the checksums.

Also please post whether your Ubuntu is 32 or 64-bit (e.g. just post the output of `uname -r`)

Comment: My system is 64 bit and running above 2 commands doesn't return anything how does it work?

Comment: `wget` downloads a list of files. `md5sum` check-sums your system files. The commands don't output anything but they produces 2 files: dpkg-1.16.0~ubuntu7-file-list and my-dpkg-checksums

Comment: Sorry not noticing the files, yea Ive those 2 files but is it still helpful as I'm using 11.10 64 bit and I think your list is for 10.04? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out one package (ubuntu-docs) was in an inconsistant state, which lead to the error message shown above.

I found this post on [UbuntuFormus](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=274844) and used

`sudo dpkg --force-all -r ubuntu-docs`

to force the removal of all ubuntu-docs related package information. apt-get/aptitude purge/remove (even with force) didn't work because of the inconsistant state.

**Be cautious when using this command because it might destroy your system**

Comment: The link requires login.

Answer (score 0):

First off. Do not delete the dpkg binary and try to download it with wget that is a horrible idea.

Second off. Are you using NTFS or an EncryptFs volume? This sounds a lot like:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/573696 and or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/524919

The suggestion is to move back to an ext3 file system. More information about the system you are on including the Ubuntu release and the filesystem where these files are being accessed would be helpful.