# Can"t install anything from Ubuntu Software Center after trying to install Ubuntu restricted extras

Tags: 11.10

I tried to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras in the Terminal. Now when ever I try to install an app or something I get this File"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py" line 968, in simulate trans. unauthenticated = self._simulate_help(trans)
What do I do?????

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68257/cant-install-remove-upgrade-any-package)?

Essentially in that thread and the one it links to:`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
From the man page this:

```
         Configure  a package which has been unpacked but not yet config‐
              ured.  If -a or --pending  is  given  instead  of  package,  all
              unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.
```

So, you're just trying to get your packages in a consistent state.  Then a`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to get to latest...from the terminal.  If it fails, note what packages it complains about.

Then you can force remove/purge/reinstall them.

"How do I purge and re-install"
`sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-restricted-*`
You may need a -f in there if something is in an inconsistent state.
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: ok, now it is back where it was in the terminal Configuring tts-mscorefonts- installer. So I just let it finish? How will I know? Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, let it finish.  If you interrupt an installation process it can leave your system in an inconsistent state.  If it's going through the fonts, you're probably going to get prompted to agree to something.   Agree, and let it run.

Comment: If it's still trying at this point, then the package didn't download properly and you need to force purge at least that package.  Safer to purge and reinstall restricted-extras

Comment: ok how do I purge and reinstall?

Comment: say's that E:dpkg was interrupted, you must manually  run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: so re-run that and then proceed.  if the configure -a command is what got the package in the 'installing' procedure use the -f flag i suggested