# Ubuntu Software Centre - Confusion with Installing Software - Adobe Flash Problems - 12.04

Tags: software-center

I am a newcomer to Ubuntu 12.04, and I've encountered some problems or confusion with using the OS, particularly with Ubuntu Software Center (which was one of the reasons I got Ubuntu Linux).

When I go into the Software Center I find it confusing as to how to download and install a program. For example, Audacity, doesn't not have an "Install" button, but a "Use This Source" from an apparent "universe" source (I don't know what this means). I click it, it shows in the "Progress" bar, and then disappears. I look into the "History" and it does not mention anything being installed. I go into the Search and it's not installed as an application (I don't even know where it is on my computer!). This happens for most Apps I want, including Chromium, etc.

I used to get a "Check your Internet Connection" message, but I have an internet connection (Moxilla Firefox runs, as does update manager) albeit a little slow.

Also, I don't have Adobe Flash and I have the same problem as above when trying to install it, and I read that it doesn't even work for Ubuntu 12.04.

I also want to install synaptic, but I can't install anything at all. Basically, to me, Ubuntu is useless without the Software Center.

Please help, and thanks for your time.

Troubled Linux User

(P.S. I am not very experienced as a programmer and understand Terminal that well, but I can copy and paste commands - I already tried sudo apt-get update )

Answer (score 1):

- **Why you have to click "Use this source"?**

  There are four type of software in ubuntu world

  1. Main - Officially supported software.
  2. Restricted - Supported software that is not available under a completely free license.
  3. Universe  - Community maintained software, i.e. not officially supported software.
  4. Multiverse -Software that is not free.

When you install a system , only `main` is activated. For any other software listed in other three category , you have to click on use this source. Once done it won't ask for  other software that are listed in the source. In `Restricted` they have drivers, flash plugins ,mp3 etc. So once restricted is enabled say for mp3, you don't have to click "Use this source" button for other software like drivers,flash.

[read more](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

- For Other issues : Possibly you are facing this

[Can't install/remove/upgrade any package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68257/cant-install-remove-upgrade-any-package)

[Can"t install anything from Ubuntu Software Center after trying to install Ubuntu restricted extras](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113110/cant-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center-after-trying-to-install-ubunt)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same problem and found a solution.

Software Centre --> Edit --> Repositories

Click all repositories from there. And then click Close. Here's the tricky part.

If it displays a dialogue box that has a reload button you're all good to go if you click on it. But if it doesn't, then just close Software Centre and go to terminal.

Type the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If it asks for your password give your password. This will update your repositories. When that is done, close the Terminal and go back to Software Centre to install as many packages as you like.